# Can you install both Xcode 3 and Xcode 4 preview 6?

Tags: xcode, ios, xcode4

Is it possible to have both Xcode 3 and Xcode 4 on the same OS instance? Is it possible to write production code in Xcode 4 and then compile it for app store in Xcode 3 ? (From practical point of view)

Comment: I think Xcode 4 is still under NDA ?

Answer (score 3):

You can install XCode into any folder, you don't have to use the default. 
Mark is right, don't upgrade the Unix package. I make a Beta folder and install the betas into that folder.

Answer (score 3):

Well yes and no.  :)

As of today with Xcode 4 GM seed, IF YOU USE THE DEFAULT LOCATION, it looks like Xcode 4 will now overwrite your /Developer and replace your Xcode 3.x. I think this is fairly new, as I have installed several of the earlier betas and have not had this happen.

So, as of now, I am a happy Xcode 4 user!  <:/

Regards,

Steve O'Sullivan

Answer (score 2):

You can install both Xcode 3 and 4 at the same time: Xcode 4 is installed into `/Xcode4` while Xcode 3 is installed into the usual `/Developer`.

However, be advised that if you upgrade the UNIX development package, it *will* replace the Xcode 3 and stock Mac OS X versions of certain command line tools with the Xcode 4 versions.

For the most part, you'll need to use Xcode 3 for any code heading to the app store.